# Is fedora 20 stable or not?

Tags: fedora

I am thinking of updating my fedora to fedora 20 and I was thinking whether it will be a good idea or not and if fedora is stable or not?

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/ferocious-fedora-20-review-cutting-edge-linux-still-as-sharp-as-ever-7000024537/

Comment: Fedora is cutting edge, If you want to have stable Linux, try Redhat Enterprise or CentOS or SUSE Enterprise...

Answer (score 4):

For fedora, 20 is very stable. I've been using it for many months. Enough time has gone by that patches have stabilized it nicely. Just remember Fedora is a test bed for new technologies for Redhat.